# A measure of non-reflexivity of Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and define

$\gamma(X)=\sup\{|\lim\limits_{n}\lim\limits_{m}\langle x^{*}_{m},x_{n}\rangle-\lim\limits_{m}\lim\limits_{n}\langle x^{*}_{m},x_{n}\rangle|:(x_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence in $B_{X}$, $(x^{*}_{m})_{m}$ is a sequence in $B_{X^{*}}$ and all the involved limits exist$\}$.

Obviously, $\gamma(X)=0$ if and only if $X$ is reflexive. Moreover, $\gamma(X)\geq 1$ for every non-reflexive space $X$. Here are some examples.

1. $\gamma(c_{0})=1$ (due to A. Kryczka, S. Prus and M. Szczepanik, 2000).
2. $\gamma(\ell_{1})=2$ (due to B. Cascales, O. F. K. Kalenda, and J. Spurn'{y}, 2012). Consequently, $\gamma(L_{1}[0,1])=\gamma(C[0,1])=\gamma(\ell_{\infty})=2$. Actually, I observe that $\gamma(X)=2$ provided that $X$ contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $\ell_{1}$.
3. $\gamma(\mathcal{J})=1$, where $\mathcal{J}$ is the James space. This is due to myself.

Question 1. $\gamma(X)=1$ or $2$ for every non-reflexive Banach space $X$ ?

Question 2. For each $t\in [1,2]$, is there a Banach space $X$ with $\gamma(X)=t$ ?

Thank you !